# NSManagedObjectContext save causes NSTextField to lose focus

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data, focus, nstextfield

This is a really strange problem I'm seeing in my app. I have an NSTextField bound to an attribute of an NSManagedObject, but whenever the object is saved the textfield loses focus. I'm continuously updating the value of the binding, so this is far from ideal.

Has anyone seen anything like this before, and (hopefully) found a solution?

Comment: Do you save the context on every change? The Textfield losing focus is normal behavior on NSManagedObjectContext save. Check NSEditor protocol for additional information

Comment: Well not on every change - it's set to save on a timed delay, and only if the context has changes. I wasn't aware of the NSEditor protocol - I'll have to rethink this a little - thanks!

Comment: I use the autosave functionality that came with 10.7 for my NSPersistentDocument based App. Now that the save operations are handled automatically my text fields lose focus always after typing two characters. Maybe I'm missing something, but I think there should be an easy fix for that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so thanks to Martin for pointing out that I should read the docs a little more closely. This is expected behaviour, and here's what I did to get around it (use your judgement as to whether this is appropriate for you):

I save my context once every 3 seconds, checking at the start if the context has any changes before I bother executing the actual `save:` method on my `NSManagedObjectContext`. I added a simple incrementing/decrementing `NSUInteger` (`_saveDisabler`) to my Core Data controller class that is modified via the following methods:

```
- (void)enableSaves {
    if (_saveDisabler > 0) {
        _saveDisabler -= 1;
    }   
}

- (void)disableSaves {
    _saveDisabler += 1;
}
```

Then all I do in my custom `saveContext` method is do a simple check at the top:

```
if (([moc hasChanges] == NO) || (_saveDisabler > 0)) {
    return YES;
}
```

This prevents the save from occurring, and means that the focus is not stolen from any of my custom textfield subclasses. For completeness, I also subclassed NSTextField and enable/disable saves in my Core Data controller from the following methods:

```
- (void)textDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)notification;
- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

It might be a little messy, but it works for me. I'm keen to hear of cleaner/less convoluted methods if anyone has done this successfully in another way.

Comment: The downside to this is that if a user is in the habit of leaving their cursor in a text field at all times you will never save.

I usually take the approach of having all my textfields/tokefields/etc. bindings set to continuously update and then something similar to @cocoafan to restore the firstResponder and selection.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the issue recently and fixed it by changing the way the NSTextField was bound to the NSManagedObject attribute. Instead of binding the value of the text field to the selection.[attribute] key path of the NSArrayController, I bound the arrayController.selection.[attribute] keyPath of the view controller that had a proper outlet pointing to the controller.

For some reason, the NSTextField doesn't loose focus when the NSManagedObjectContext is saved if bound this way.

Comment: It fixes my problem as well. I've used those tricks of decoupling the bindings already in the past. I wonder if anyone sees a real problem here. It sounds to me as this should be fine (obviously if only one piece of UI can change that TextField's underlying Core Data attribute)!

Comment: How would you do that, when the text field is inside a text field cell in a table view?

Comment: I have the same problem that @Sbhklr, my text field is inside a view in a View Based NSTableView.

Answer (score 4):

I want to share my solution. It will work for all fields without modification.
I have optimized it for this posting and removed some error checking, logging and thread safety.

```
- (BOOL)saveChanges:(NSError **)outError {
  BOOL result = YES;
  @try {
    NSError *error = nil; 
    if ([self hasChanges])  {

    // Get field editor
    NSResponder *responder = [[NSApp keyWindow] firstResponder];
    NSText *editor = [[NSApp keyWindow] fieldEditor: NO forObject: nil];
    id editingObject = [editor delegate];
    BOOL isEditing = (responder == editor);
    NSRange range;
    NSInteger editedRow, editedColumn;

   // End editing to commit the last changes
   if (isEditing) {

     // Special case for tables
     if ([editingObject isKindOfClass: [NSTableView class]]) {
       editedRow = [editingObject editedRow];
       editedColumn = [editingObject editedColumn];
     }

     range = [editor selectedRange];
     [[NSApp keyWindow] endEditingFor: nil];
   }

   // The actual save operation
   if (![self save: &error]) {
     if (outError != nil)
        *outError = error;
      result = NO;
    } else {
      result = YES;
    }

    // Now restore the field editor, if any.
    if (isEditing) {
      [[NSApp keyWindow] makeFirstResponder: editingObject];
      if ([editingObject isKindOfClass: [NSTableView class]])
        [editingObject editColumn: editedColumn row: editedRow withEvent: nil select: NO];
        [editor setSelectedRange: range];
      }
    }
  } @catch (id exception) {
    result = NO;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Except of course the edit point may not be at the end (or there could even be a selection). Just capture the [editor selectedRange] NSRange before ending editing, then [editor setSelectedRange:] using the saved NSRange.

Comment: You're right. I had already improved the code and added support for NSTableView. I have now edited my answer to share it with you. Please note that this is a stripped version of my actual code, which also includes thread safety and error handling.